# I need to scrape external values from cex.io and coinbase.com

Tags: php

coinbase.com
1. Class = top-balance

Cex.io
2. Id = ticker-GHS-BTC-price
3. Id = ticker-FHA-BTC
4. Id = ticker-FHM-BTC

at a 1 min interval then take 1 and multiply it by 2,3,4 to create separate values then multiple each by 50 then make a db entry.

Im a complete noob with php.. much thanks!

Comment: So you seriously think just because you lack some knowledge and are lazy to learn - we will do the job for you? Try the same trick with your dentist or car mechanic and tell us your experience.

Comment: Do you expect a response to your fallacious statement? I've dont research and its beyond my current understanding.

Comment: "and its beyond my current understanding" --- learn from the basics then. When you are ready - you'll implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you're getting the information from Coinbase or Cex.io, but if it's an XML feed try learning SimpleXML.  It's a great tool for PHP and makes things really easy to manage.  Then you can find the entry you need and assign it to a variable.

It would really help if you provided some URLs for the data feeds.  If you're planning on scraping the webpage itself, please, PLEASE try to find an API first.  I made that mistake when I was starting out.  An API will give you a URL of just XML or just JSON usually.  Either way with basic PHP tools like SimpleXML you can turn these into arrays with all your data.

As far as the math parts, just use your basic math symbols.  They work the same as most lanugages:

- multiply by 2: `$variable_x2 = $variable * 2`

If you're dealing with a lot of multiplying, try a `for` loop and make an array.

If you're going to put these in a database, I'll assume you're using MySQL.  That's one of the most common database formats.  Make sure that all your tables, etc. are set up before trying to write to them.  If you're new to MySQL too, use a utility like PHPMyAdmin, which will make the process of setting up much easier.  It's pre-installed on most webhosts.

Now for the whole "one minute intervals" thing.  Either you're going to have a loop with some wait time and keep the page open on infinite load, which I don't recommend because it makes some web hosts mad, or you're going to use CRON.  Most hosts I deal with have a simple CRON setup: you specify the file to run and how often to run it.  I don't know how you're set up though.

This should get you started.  If you want to revise your question with more information on your issues and how your host is set up and how you're getting your data, I'm sure we can help a lot more.  But as a starter try what I've mentioned.  PHP.net is your friend: look up ANYTHING you don't understand!